# Why debug certificate is not safe to sign android APKs?

Tags: android, security, cryptography, certificate

[Android Documents](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode) said that it's not safe to publish an app with a debug certificate, but I don't know why. What does "insecure by design" means, how the debug certificate is designed?

> Because the debug certificate is created by the build tools and is
> insecure by design, most app stores (including the Google Play Store)
> do not accept apps signed with a debug certificate for publishing.

Answer (score 2):

[This page indicates](https://mobile-security.gitbook.io/mobile-security-testing-guide/android-testing-guide/0x05i-testing-code-quality-and-build-settings) that the problem is that the debug certificate does not have a trust anchor, so the certificate can easily be replaced. Here is the sample they present:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs example.apk

sm     11116 Fri Nov 11 12:07:48 ICT 2016 AndroidManifest.xml

      X.509, CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
      [certificate is valid from 3/24/16 9:18 AM to 8/10/43 9:18 AM]
      [CertPath not validated: Path doesn\'t chain with any of the trust anchors]
(...)
```

Comment: Hi Ken Y-N. If you consider something spam please do not close-vote. Instead flag as spam. Do not comment that you close-voted, comment to tell others to flag, instead of downvoting or close-voting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is signed with the Android SDK tool and all have the same password in order to use it for later debugging tasks. so it is recommended to use a CA-certified certificate.